# HTTrack stores extensionless pages with a .html appended

Tags: web, archive, web-crawler, scraping

I'd like to mirror an old site of mine to local files. I've used httrack for this in the past, but I'm having a problem this time that I really thought I figured out before, but can't seem to now.

My site has a lot of extensionless pages, which httrack downloads as a file and appends .html to. It then updates all the links in other pages to reference this altered path. Problem is- this is a new path, not matching the old structure. I'd prefer that it create a folder matching the extensionless file, and then drop an index.html file inside that folder.

Can httrack do this, or do I need to find a different tool?

Comment: A bit late, but in case it's useful to anyone... it *sounds* like the URLs of the site you're trying to archive don't end in a slash. e.g. `mydomain.com/dir/subdir` rather than `mydomain.com/dir/subdir/`. httrack will interpret the former as file, rather than a directory (so it creates `subdir.html` instead of `subdir/index.html`).